# Submit Button didn't do anything

Tags: javascript, html

Here I'm trying to make a QnA website. So here is the HTML code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Questions</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Questions</h1>
  <form action="questions.php" method="post" onsubmit='event.preventDefault() ;sendForm1("ask-question")' name="ask-question">
    <h3>Ask a Question</h3>
    <!--Adds textarea field to write a question-->
    <textarea name="ask-question" rows=5 cols=25 id="your-question">Why do you want to draw art?</textarea><br>
    <!--Submit button to send question to email and redirects to result.html without opening an email inbox. The problem is I have no idea how to make it send to my email.-->
    <input type=submit value=Ask name=ask>
  </form>
  <a href="/">Go back home</a>
  <br>
  <p>No Questions available yet!</p>
  <h2>Be the First to ask!</h2>
  <h3>Type the question in the text box then click Ask</h3><a href="faq.html">or go to FAQ</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Here i put some meanings about the code and you'll find out most problems but the main problem is I can't get the Submit button to work. Or some it just reloads the website.
Here is the preview of the code.
[image: Click to view Code html Preview]
How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure nothing happens? like, nothing in the browser developer tools to suggests there's an error? since `sendForm1` function doesn't exist at all?

Comment: Share your javascript snippet

Comment: Sorry I don't use javascipt at all just html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't working because you are using `onsubmit = event.preventDefault()` which prevents the default behaviour of form submission. That's why you are not getting redirected to the `result.html` page. Remove the `event.preventDefault()` and this should be working